# How to find intersection of two arcs on sphere with CGAL

Tags: cgal

I have 2 arcs on unit sphere in 3-dimensional space and I want to know do they intersects or not with using of CGAL. I know that i must use doIntersect function, but I don't understand how to define arks (which parameters I must transmit to :Circular_arc_point_3).

For example, i have 2 points in spherical coordinates:

> phi = 0, psi = 0, r = 1
>
> phi = 45, psi = 45, r = 1

(They define arc on unit sphere)

Which parameters I must set in:

> Circular_arc_point_3 p = Circular_arc_point_3(?, ?, ?);

Answer (score 0):

You can construct an arc from a supporting circle and its two endpoints.

See the following documentation pages:

- [Circular_arc_3](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Circular_kernel_3/classCGAL_1_1Circular__arc__3.html)
- [Circular_arc_point_3](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Circular_kernel_3/classCGAL_1_1Circular__arc__point__3.html)
- [Circle_3](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Circle__3.html)